# Saving an element as a index in a object

Tags: javascript, object

I'd like to save a DOM element in a object. But not as a value, i want save it as a key of the object. But i think the core of javascript is not able to do that.

```
data={}
data[$('div#a')] = 'A';
data[$('div#b')] = 'B';
console.log(data[$('div#a')]); //return B
```

Do you know some way to save the element in a index object?

---

Imagine i have XXXXXX elements on my document. If i want to access to the element properties when some event happen on it i dont want to iterate XXXXXX elements to find it.

Why i don't use data of jquery for two reasons:

1. I want to do it on native javascript
2. I dont want another array to iterate separate data from the elementid

So the perfect way to do it was have only one object with the elements on the key to acces them easy. And if i want iterate them i only have to do for i in data

Comment: Why dont you store the `id` attribute of the element as the key? Anyway ID is going to be unique.

Comment: sounds like an "XY problem"...

Comment: because some elements doesn't have id @stevanity.

Comment: The elements of the DOM has some native unique id?

Comment: No they donot have any unique ID. Would it be possible to assign unique ID to these elements to make life easier?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects will only accept strings as keys, and JS will use `.toString()` if you try to use anything else as a key, typically resulting in everything being stored under the (single) key `"[object Object]"`.

Is there any reason you can't use [`$('#a').data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to store the data associated with that element directly on the element?

Failing that, assuming that every such element has an ID, just use the element ID as the object key.

NB: ES6 has a `Map` object which *can* use [arbitrary keys](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/10/09/ecmascript-6-collections-part-2-maps/), but that's only an experimental feature in current browsers.  However even then you would have to use the actual element as the key rather than a jQuery wrapped `$(element)` object, since `$('#a') !== $('#a')` - you would have to use the *exact same* original jQuery object each time you access the map, not a newly constructed object.

Comment: I'd like to do it with native javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript objects only accept string as key.

So if you try to give key value other than string, javascript will internally call .toString() method of that object and use return  value of it as key.

Comment: correct, and the element is converted to string, and the index saved is always "[object HTMLInputElement]"

Answer (score 0):

Object keys have to be stings.

You can use the `data` method to associate anything to the element:

```
$('div#a').data('name', 'A');
$('div#b').data('name', 'B');
console.log($('div#a').data('name')); //return B
```